# allow access from only specific referrer with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to block access to my .html files to those who do not come from a specific referrer. Referrer domain is not primary domain. (referrer domain looks like this: http://sub.domain.com/3452434512 where this part: "3452434512" is always different)

This is how my .htaccess file looks like (found example on apache.org):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!subdomain.example.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.html" "http://redirect.here.com" [R]
```

But it does not work, it redirects all traffic to redirect domain. Where is the mistake?

Found several older (from 2004 and 2009) examples that did not work either.

EDIT: Version of Apache is 2.2 so I tried this version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !subdomain.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(html|jpg|png|php)$ http://redirect.here.com [R,NC]
```

But this didnt work too.

Comment: Http_referrer can be easily spoofed. Don't rely on it for security.

Comment: In this case it suits my needs. Referrer domain is very specific and impossible to guess.